# How can I use the ta.correlation function in PineScript (Tradingview) to show the correlation of two different symbols?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to Pine and my problem is that when using the ta.correlation function, I can't figure out how to define two different symbols for which the correlation is displayed.

I only manage to load in as input the price data (with close, open etc. ) from the same symbol, which of course makes little sense.

How do I have to proceed further?
Do I have to load another symbol with request.security first?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use input.symbol to take the two instruments as input and then pull their close using request.security. Then you can calculate correlation on that and plot the same

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Correlation By Rohit")
symbol1 = input.symbol("CL1!","Symbol1")
symbol2 = input.symbol("UKOIL","Symbol2")
close1=request.security(symbol1, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off)
close2=request.security(symbol2,timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off)
c=ta.correlation(close1,close2,10)
plot(c)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
How can I refer to the correlation coefficient then ?

Can I simply say: 

if c > 0.5 
    plot("50")

Comment: you can write like plot(c>0.5?50:c<-0.5?-50:0)